# Scala WS returning 404 for a existing route

Tags: scala, web-services, playframework, http-status-code-404, playframework-2.3

I have a **/ws/foo/:param** route, which works perfectly on dev environment.

On the other hand, in production, it works fine when called through the browser, but returns a **404** when it is accessed from a system to another.

This is how I am making the request:

```
Await.ready(WS.url(s"/ws/foo/$param").withHeaders("Authorization" -> token).get().map { response =>
  response.body
}, 5000 millis).value.get
```

Comment: is your route `/ws/foo` or `/ws/foo/:id`? in your example you are requesting `/ws/foo/$param`.

Comment: Please also show your routes file and how you are accessing the endpoint in the browser

Comment: Hey! the route is /ws/foo/:id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The hosts file was missing the domains on the server.